# IOS app crashes on first load in production build - React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-updates

I am in a very confusing situation where my expo built app runs perfectly fine in my local environment but after building with EAS and when I run it on TestFlight the app crashes on the first load. But surprisingly when I open again it works fine.

Errors based on App store connect crash report

[image]

Error recorded on my crash logging service sentry
[image]

With current debugging I am only able to find that EXUpdatesAppController is an expo-updates module but not sure why its throwing an exception.

Would be great if someone can help me out with this as I am not too experienced with Expo and React native

Comment: Found any solutions on this?

Comment: same boat, very frustrating

Comment: Same here, please any solutions?

Comment: No solution yet. When I build using the older command in place of EAS it works perfectly fine. Most probably some issue with EAS bundle optimisation

Comment: Same here, I've been blocked on the same problem for the past 10 days..
Do you have any solution for this ? It seems the problem comes from EAS.
Thank you very much

Comment: Same here anyone got any further with this?

Comment: @HarshNagalla, were you able to solve this? my entire company is frozen because of this, Please let me know if you figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

in my specific situation my expo was SDK 47, i upgraded it to 48 and looked issueses with npx expo doctor. Some npm modules were outdated. When i upgrade them my problem is solved.

Edit: i also rebuid and resubmit the app.